# I used TextView as a button but it can't perform its action. App always crashed after I press a button

Tags: android

I am trying to use `TextView` as a `Button` but it can't perform its action. App always stopped working after press this TextView button.

I added `android:clickable="true"` and `android:onClick="perform_action"` section on my XML code. But whenever I hit press the button, app stopped working.

This is a Activity_main.xml code (it doesn't contain a TextView that I am trying to use as a button):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="157dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="157dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="157dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="157dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="371dp"
        android:text="Нэвтрэх"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etToken" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etToken"
        android:layout_width="282dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="209dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="65dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Token-оо оруулаад нэвтэрнэ үү!"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ok"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is my main activity. Main activity guides user to another page (or fragment) which contains the TextView that I am trying to use as a button (Just like a simple login section).:

```
    package com.example.demo;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.InputType;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.PopupWindow;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.Set;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText txt;
    private String token = "123456";
    private Button btn, btn1;
    private String Anhaaramj_ogoh_ortoo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView ortoohead = findViewById(R.id.ortoohead);
        txt = findViewById(R.id.etToken);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.ok);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                check(txt.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
    public void showAlert(View view){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert1.setMessage("Уучлаарай таны оруулсан token буруу байна!")
                .setPositiveButton("Дахин оролдох", new 
   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create();
        alert1.show();
    }
    public void check(String Tkn){
        if(Tkn.equals(token)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, harnaa.class);
            txt.setText(null);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else{
            showAlert(null);
            txt.setText(null);
        }
    }

    public void perform_action(View v)
    {
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.ortoohead);

        //alter text of textview widget
        tv.setText("This text view is clicked");

        //assign the textview forecolor
        tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
```

This `activity_attention.xml` contains my `TextView` which is the last TextView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valuebody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/valuehead"
        android:text="Анхаарамж өгөх болсон шалтгаанаа бичнэ үү?" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valuehead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/epbody"
        android:text="Анхаарамжийн утга:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/epbody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/ephead"
        android:text="КП-КМ"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ephead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/spbody"
        android:text="Дуусах цэг:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spbody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/sphead"
        android:text="КМ-ПК"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sphead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/posbody"
        android:text="Эхлэх Цэг:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/posbody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/poshead"
        android:text="Таны байршил"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/poshead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/hoorondbody"
        android:text="Ажил хийх байршил:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hoorondbody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/hoorondhead"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Наран-Элгэн-Оорцог-Энгэр"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hoorondhead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/ehlehbody"
        android:text="Хоорондын зам:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dip" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/ehlehbody"
        android:layout_below="@id/ehlehhead"
        android:text="2019/07/25 22:35"
        android:textSize="15dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ehlehhead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/ortoobody"
        android:text="Эхлэх огноо:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ortoobody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/ortoohead"
        android:text="Өртөөний нэр"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ortoohead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="perform_action"
        android:text="Анхаарамж өгөх өртөөд:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/valuebody"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:onClick="SetOrtoo"
        android:text="Button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally Attention.java it a Fragment:

```
    package com.example.demo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class Attention extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_attention, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Check the LogCat window so you know what the error is. Does `ortoohead` exists? Is it a `TextView`?

Comment: Post your crash log here

Comment: Yeah ortoohead exists its a Id of the Textview.

Comment: Sorry Leo my code looks so complicated and my english is also bad.

Comment: Then you can simply modify the view passed in the event handler. `View v` is effectively the `TextView` you've just clicked. But unless you post the logs we'll never know for sure

Comment: Hi Leo. Its my first post sorry. I created Fragment. And put the textview (That I try to use as a Button) on the fragment. Main activity doesn't contain this text. I have to say that. This is cause of this error?

Comment: On a fragment? Then that code should be moved to your fragment

Comment: Could you please update the question as you moved the code to fragment?

Comment: I am beginner as i said. And I noticed that buttons can't find functions from my fragment. So that I have wrote it on my Main_Activity. Then buttons can recognize the function. But.. Ok i will post my full code. Thanks for your comments and time that you have spent for me :D.

Comment: Birju Vachhani. Ok i will thanks for your kindness :D.

Comment: @Leo I updated my post. Help me please :D.

Comment: @BachVu I updated my post. Help me please :D.

Comment: @BirjuVachhani I updated my post. Help me please :D.

Comment: You are accessing Textview inside activity whose layout is activity_main which does not contain this textview either add this in your layout or perform action inside Attention fragment

Comment: R.Id.ortoohead is reason behind crash

Comment: @NehaRathore If i manage to perform this action inside fragment, error will solved right? I don't know much about fragment. :D. Thanks for ur suggestion I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to click the `TextView` from fragment so you need to implement like this -

**Just replace your `Attention` fragment code with below snippet.**

```
package com.example.demo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

    public class Attention extends Fragment {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_attention, container, false);
        }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        TextView ortooheadTextView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ortoohead);
            ortooheadTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TextView clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
                }
            });
    }

    }
```

Comment: I tried sir. But i get an error at this line TextView ortooheadTextView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ortoohead);
error says that: Unreachable statment

Comment: After `return` of any method java doesn't take any code to compile. That's why it showed Unreachable statment.

Now I have edited my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Woow thank you sir. Its finally working. Can i replace Toast part with Dialog? Look at the SetOrtoo function. Can I replace Toast part with this function?

Comment: Sure. You can do what you want.

Comment: I can'r replace that. I just replaced your Toast code with my dialog code. And i get an error at these 2 lines:               
  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                final EditText input = new EditText(this);
error says that: in Builder cannot be applied to (anonymous.android.view.View.OnClickLisetener). Help me please sir. :D

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plnLs6aST1M

this tutorial may help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML you have text View and in Java code you're using button to perform click event. Your text View name is ortoohead this declare your view globally and give click listener view your fragment class like this

> View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_level_fragment, container, false);
>   Textview ortoohead = root.findViewById(R.id.ortoohead);

```
 ortoohead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
             final EditText input = new EditText(this);
             input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | 
             InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE);
             alert.setTitle("Анхаарамж өгөх өртөө")
            .setView(input)
            .setPositiveButton("Хадгалах", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Anhaaramj_ogoh_ortoo = input.getText().toString();
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Цуцлах", new 
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alert.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi bro. I have tried ur method. And I gave a error. It says that in Builder cannot be applied to (anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener). I am beginner bro. Thanks for you kindness.

Comment: your text vew is in fragment in this layout activity_attention.xml so call the above my example code in fragment not in main activity you will not get error

Comment: Hi bro. I am absolute beginner as i said. I can't add your code in my fragments. I tried lot but still getting an error. Exactly which part of the fragment I have to replace your code. Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: Call example code in this **Attention extends Fragment** and in your main_acivity use FrameLayout  use this site and learn fragment how to implement(https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/)

Comment: Okay. Thank you got it bro.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a view variable globally in fragment,

```
View view;

@OnClick(R.id.ortoohead)
public void clickButton() {
    // Implement your code here...
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment__complaints, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}
```

Use Butterknife to bind your view

CHANGE IN GRADLE

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:(insert latest version)'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:(insert latest version)'
```

Reference

```
https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/
```